# Jenkinsfile deployment failing at cucumber step

Tags: jenkins, cucumber

My Jenkins deployment is failing with the following error:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] cucumber
Error when executing always post condition:
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
```

Here is where cucumber is defined:

```
      always {
        cucumber reportTitle: 'Apickli test report',
              fileIncludePattern: '**/reports.json',
              jsonReportDirectory: "target",
              sortingMethod: 'ALPHABETICAL',
              trendsLimit: 10
      }
    }
```

This is a new Jenkins build and this same deployment works on the "old" server. I have the cucumber plugin added. Could I be missing another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to Jenkins and figured out that this always {} statement runs after each stage and needed to fix an issue in the first stage.